# How to DRY out this ruby code

Tags: ruby, dry

I would like to DRY out this code. I can't  seem to figure out how though.

```
def get_all_verb_nodes
    all_verb_nodes = @all_nodes_ins_del_nodes.select { |node|
    previous_node = node.xpath('preceding-sibling::w:r').last
    base_word = previous_node.text.split.last.strip.delete('.!?,:') if previous_node
  words = get_node_text(node)
  next_node = node.next_element
  next_node_is_insert_or_delete = is_insert_or_delete?(next_node.name) if next_node
  next_node_word = next_node.text.strip if next_node
  words.length <= 2 && words.any? { |word| is_a_verb?(base_word+word) || is_a_verb?(word) && !is_pluralized?(base_word+word, base_word+next_node_word) } && !next_node_is_insert_or_delete
    }
end


def get_all_article_nodes
    all_article_nodes = @all_nodes_ins_del_nodes.select { |node|
    previous_node = node.xpath('preceding-sibling::w:r').last
    base_word = previous_node.text.split.last.strip.delete('.!?,:') if previous_node
  words = get_node_text(node) 
  next_node = node.next_element
  next_node_is_insert_or_delete = is_insert_or_delete?(next_node.name) if next_node
  next_node_word = next_node.text.strip if next_node
  words.length <= 2 && words.any? { |word| @articleset.include?(word) || (@articleset.include?(base_word) if word == 'n') } && !@articleset.include?(next_node_word) && !next_node_is_insert_or_delete
    }
end
```

Both are almost identical except for the last line which defines the specific requirement of the function.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: It looks quite procedural and quite hard to read with the comments, but blocks and calling `yield` is probably what you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first cut at it. I moved things around so they were grouped logically and to facilitate the yield.

```
def get_all_nodes
  @all_nodes_ins_del_nodes.select do |node|
    previous_node = node.xpath('preceding-sibling::w:r').last
    base_word = previous_node.text.split.last.strip.delete('.!?,:') if previous_node

    next_node = node.next_element
    next_node_is_insert_or_delete = is_insert_or_delete?(next_node.name) if next_node
    next_node_word = next_node.text.strip if next_node

    words = get_node_text(node) 
    words.length <= 2 &&
    !next_node_is_insert_or_delete &&
    yield(words, base_word, next_node_word)
  end
end

all_verb_nodes = get_all_nodes do |words, base_word, next_node_word|
  words.any? do |word|
    is_a_verb?(base_word + word) ||
    is_a_verb?(word) &&
    !is_pluralized?(base_word + word, base_word + next_node_word)
  end
end

all_article_nodes = get_all_nodes do |words, base_word, next_node_word|
  !@articleset.include?(next_node_word) &&
  words.any? do |word|
    @articleset.include?(word) || (@articleset.include?(base_word) if word == 'n')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you seph for your ideas and code. I will give it a try and get back to you. From what I can see it gets me on the right path and answers my question.